# LoadLibraryEx ignores side-by-side manifest

Tags: c++, winapi, loadlibrary, side-by-side, activation-context-api

Does `LoadLibraryEx` function use side-by-side manifests? I have bar.dll with embedded SxS manifest, and that manifest describes version of this bar.dll, other dll file foo.dll has manifest that lists bar.dll as dependency, with specified version. But when I try to load bar.dll from foo.dll with `LoadLibraryEx("bar.dll", NULL, 0)` I see (with enabled sls with gflags) that it ignores these manifests, and loads first version of bar.dll that it sees in searchpath, if I define `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED` and use `LoadLibrary` it finds right version, but this `ISOLATION_AWARE_ENABLED` doesn't affect behaviour of `LoadLibraryEx`, I need to load right version with `LoadLibraryEx` because `LoadLibraryEx` is used implicitly for delayed loading of dll's. Is `LoadLibraryEx` supposed to work like this, or is it some problem in my project configuration?

foo dll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity name="foo" version="0.1.2.3" type="win32"/>
<dependency>
    <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="bar" version="0.1.2.3" type="win32" />
    </dependentAssembly>
</dependency>
<file name="foo.dll">
</file>
</assembly>
```

bar.dll

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<assembly xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1" manifestVersion="1.0">
<assemblyIdentity name="bar" version="0.1.2.3" type="win32"/>
<file name="bar.dll">
</file>
</assembly>
```

Comment: are you activate manifest from *foo.dll* before call `LoadLibrary` ? sure that no. by default active is exe manifest. you need activate you foo.dll manifest before call `LoadLibrary` and deactivate after. exactly this is do `IsolationAwareLoadLibraryA`. so you need in fooentry point save activation context - by call `GetCurrentActCtx` and then shell `LoadLibrary` call into `ActivateActCtx` `DeactivateActCtx`

Comment: @RbMm, No, of course I don't touch any active context functions, because I want it to create new context implicitly, when I DelayLoad some dll (Call LoadLibraryEx)

Comment: this and your error. you not need create new context but activate context from your foo.dll

Comment: _"If you call LoadLibraryEx with the name of an assembly without a path specification and the assembly is listed in the system compatible manifest, the call is automatically redirected to the side-by-side assembly."_ https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684179(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: And you can use sxstrace to see exactly what the loader does.

Comment: @RichardCritten I've seen that, I load it as LoadLibraryEx("bar.dll", NULL, 0), there is no path in first argument.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`LoadLibrary` used active activation context of the calling thread. but which is this context ? why it must be from your `foo.dll` ? why not from `xyz.dll` or from exe ? really most time active activation context was exactly from exe.

if dll have own manifest - system create activation context for this dll and save it (until dll will be unloaded) but not make it active. and this is obviously - we have multiple dlls in process, but active context only one - from which dll select it ? from exe. however system activate (make it current active) dll activation context before call it entry point. and deactivate it after entry point return. but say inside another dll functions - (who called it ?) the context already not from your dll.

so solution must be next:

define 2 global variables in dll:

```
BOOL gActCtx;
HANDLE ghActCtx
```

on `DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH` save current activation context (it from your dll manifest)

```
gActCtx = GetCurrentActCtx(&ghActCtx);
```

free it on `DLL_PROCESS_DETACH`

```
if (gActCtx) ReleaseActCtx(ghActCtx);
```

and when you need load `bar.dll` do next:

```
if (gActCtx)
{
    ULONG_PTR Cookie;

    if (ActivateActCtx(ghActCtx, &Cookie))
    {
        LoadLibraryExW(L"bar.dll", NULL, 0);

        DeactivateActCtx(0, Cookie);
    }
}
```

Comment: But shouldn't /DELAYLOAD option of linker automatically take into account this context activation? It's weird that developers of linker didn't make such obvious feature.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev - how `/DELAYLOAD` can do this ?! try set self on linker place. he generate link code, but it have no any knowledge of os. when you call function from delay load dll - linker simply call `__delayLoadHelper2` function. you must implement it yourself, or use some lib implementation. exactly here you need load correct dll as well. but this already your task, not linker

Comment: @IbraimGaniev - you can for example, if use lib implementation for delayload - on `dliStartProcessing` yourself activate context by `ActivateActCtx` and on `dliNoteEndProcessing` deactivate it. or yourself implement dll load on `dliNotePreLoadLibrary`

Comment: this works perfectly, but could you give me a link where this approach is described? I'm not sure if there are any guarantees that I'll be able to save handler to context of DLL in DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH. And is there a way to get this handler in other places of my dll's code?

Thanks in advance, and thanks again for your answer.

Comment: @IbraimGaniev - when system load dll it look for it manifest (`ISOLATIONAWARE_MANIFEST_RESOURCE_ID`) and if it present create activation context from it and save [here](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/doc/ntldr_8h_source.html#l00155). before call dll entry point - loader activate this context. so you can got it and save by call `GetCurrentActCtx`. also possible at any time get it by undocumented `LdrFindEntryForAddress`. also look this - http://simon.rozman.si/computers/wxwidgets/wxwidgets-dll-plugin